# Solarium suggester return 0 result

Tags: php, solr, solarium

I setup suggester query in solr. I have the following setting,

**Solar config**

```
  <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">FuzzyLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">productSuggest</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">string</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>

  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler" startup="lazy">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">10</str>
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

**Schema file**

```
  <field name="SpecMaterial" type="string" uninvertible="true" default="SpecMaterial" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

  <copyField source="SpecMaterial" dest="productSuggest" maxChars="30000"/>
  <field name="productSuggest" type="textSuggest" default="productSuggest" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

  <fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="textSuggest" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StandardFilterFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

I run using this below url

```
   http://localhost:8983/solr/test_products/suggest?suggest=true&suggest.dictionary=mySuggester&wt=json&suggest.q=Medium
```

But the suggester return 0 result like,

```
{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0},
  "suggest":{"mySuggester":{
      "Medium":{
        "numFound":0,
        "suggestions":[]}
       }
   }
}
```

If any mistake are there in code? And why we can use copyfeild in suggester?

Comment: Did you build the suggester values with `suggest.build=true` in a request first?

Comment: yes. I did using this URL

Comment: ```http://localhost:8983/solr/reliance_products/suggest?suggest.build=true```

Comment: The output is ***{
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":42},
  "command":"build"}***

Comment: Did you add any documents to your index, and what are their contents? (please add relevant information to the question instead of as single comments for each item)

Comment: No. I didn't add documents to my code.

Comment: So if there are no documents in your index, what should the suggester return? The suggester is built from the documents in your index to return values that are relevant to the documents inside it - i.e. to suggest possible valid values from those that are present in the index.

Comment: I have a doubt how to add document in index page?
If any procedure are there?

Comment: You can add documents for testing through the "Documents" page in the admin interface. Usually you'll send these from your application to be stored in Solr for searching.